# React-Admin <ImageInput> to upload images to rails api

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to upload images from react-admin to rails api backend using active storage.

In the documentation of react-admin it says: "Note that the image upload returns a File object. It is your responsibility to handle it depending on your API behavior. You can for instance encode it in base64, or send it as a multi-part form data" I am trying to send it as a multi-part form.

I have been reading here and there but I can not find what I want, at least a roadmap of how I should proceed.

Comment: Can you show the code you currently have, so we can help you?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually find an example in the [dataProvider section](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#decorating-your-data-provider-example-of-file-upload) of the documentation.

You have to decorate your dataProvider to enable the data upload. Here is the example of transforming the images into base64 strings before posting the resource:

```js
// in addUploadFeature.js
/**
 * Convert a `File` object returned by the upload input into a base 64 string.
 * That's not the most optimized way to store images in production, but it's
 * enough to illustrate the idea of data provider decoration.
 */
const convertFileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);

    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
});

/**
 * For posts update only, convert uploaded image in base 64 and attach it to
 * the `picture` sent property, with `src` and `title` attributes.
 */
const addUploadFeature = requestHandler => (type, resource, params) => {
    if (type === 'UPDATE' && resource === 'posts') {
        // notice that following condition can be true only when `<ImageInput source="pictures" />` component has parameter `multiple={true}`
        // if parameter `multiple` is false, then data.pictures is not an array, but single object
        if (params.data.pictures && params.data.pictures.length) {
            // only freshly dropped pictures are instance of File
            const formerPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => !(p.rawFile instanceof File));
            const newPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => p.rawFile instanceof File);

            return Promise.all(newPictures.map(convertFileToBase64))
                .then(base64Pictures => base64Pictures.map((picture64, index) => ({
                    src: picture64,
                    title: `${newPictures[index].title}`,
                })))
                .then(transformedNewPictures => requestHandler(type, resource, {
                    ...params,
                    data: {
                        ...params.data,
                        pictures: [...transformedNewPictures, ...formerPictures],
                    },
                }));
        }
    }
    // for other request types and resources, fall back to the default request handler
    return requestHandler(type, resource, params);
};

export default addUploadFeature;
```

You can then apply this on your dataProvider:

```js
// in dataProvider.js
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';
import addUploadFeature from './addUploadFeature';

const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://path.to.my.api/');
const uploadCapableDataProvider = addUploadFeature(dataProvider);

export default uploadCapableDataProvider;
```

Finally, you can use it in your admin as usual:

```
// in App.js
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';

import dataProvider from './dataProvider';
import PostList from './posts/PostList';

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={uploadCapableDataProvider}>
        <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
    </Admin>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had seen the example  but what I want is to send the image as a multipart element

Comment: @Tiamon did you do it. I want to upload a Post with Images all at once .

Answer (score 1):

When using files, use a multi-part form in the react front-end and for example multer in your API backend.

In react-admin you should create a [custom dataProvider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#decorating-your-data-provider-example-of-file-upload) and extend either the default or built a custom one. Per implementation you should handle the file/files upload. For uploading a file or files from your custom dataprovider in react-admin:

```js
// dataProvider.js
// this is only the implementation for a create

case "CREATE":
  const formData = new FormData();

  for ( const param in params.data ) {

    // 1 file
    if (param === 'file') {
      formData.append('file', params.data[param].rawFile);
      continue
    }

    // when using multiple files
    if (param === 'files') {
      params.data[param].forEach(file => {
        formData.append('files', file.rawFile);
      });
      continue
    }

    formData.append(param, params.data[param]);
  }

  return httpClient(`myendpoint.com/upload`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json });
```

From there you pick it up in your API using multer, that supports multi-part forms out-of-the-box. When using [nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload) that could look like:

```js
import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  Header,
  UseInterceptors,
  UploadedFile,
} from "@nestjs/common";
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express'

@Controller("upload")
export class UploadController {

  @Post()
  @Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
  // multer extracts file from the request body 
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  async uploadFile(
    @UploadedFile() file : Record<any, any>
  ) {
    console.log({ file })
  }
}
```

Comment: How the graphql resolver should be for this getting an error @hajnalbendeguz .any idea

Comment: A nice description at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63570461/11067065