# Nestjs Apollo graphql upload scalar

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, nestjs

I'm using nestjs graphql framework and I want to use apollo scalar upload

I have been able to use the scalar in another project that did not include nestjs.

schema.graphql
App.module.ts register graphql

```
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      resolvers: { Upload: GraphQLUpload },
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
      playground: true,
      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), './src/graphql.classes.ts'),
        outputAs: 'class',
      },
      uploads: {
        maxFileSize: 10000000, // 10 MB
        maxFiles: 5
      }
    }),
```

pets.resolver.ts mutation createPet

```
@Mutation('uploadFile')
    async uploadFile(@Args('fileUploadInput') fileUploadInput: FileUploadInput) {
        console.log("TCL: PetsResolver -> uploadFile -> file", fileUploadInput);
        return {
            id: '123454',
            path: 'www.wtf.com',
            filename: fileUploadInput.file.filename,
            mimetype: fileUploadInput.file.mimetype
        }
    }
```

pets.type.graphql

```
type Mutation {
        uploadFile(fileUploadInput: FileUploadInput!): File!
}
input FileUploadInput{
    file: Upload!
}

type File {
        id: String!
        path: String!
        filename: String!
        mimetype: String!
}
```

I expect that scalar works with nestjs but my actual result is

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Promise resolver undefined is not a function","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["createPet"],"extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","exception":{"stacktrace":["TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function","    at new Promise (<anonymous>)","    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (E:\\projectos\\Gitlab\\latineo\\latineo-api\\src\\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:119:32)","    at E:\\projectos\\Gitlab\\latineo\\latineo-api\\src\\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:62:40","    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)","    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (E:\\projectos\\Gitlab\\latineo\\latineo-api\\src\\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:41:30)","    at _loop_1 (E:\\projectos\\Gitlab\\latineo\\latineo-api\\src\\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:226:43)","    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (E:\\projectos\\Gitlab\\latineo\\latineo-api\\node_modules\\class-transformer\\TransformOperationExecutor.js:240:17)","    at ClassTransformer.plainToClass (E:\\projectos\\Gitlab\\latineo\\latineo-api\\src\\ClassTransformer.ts:43:25)","    at Object.plainToClass (E:\\projectos\\Gitlab\\latineo\\latineo-api\\src\\index.ts:37:29)","    at ValidationPipe.transform (E:\\projectos\\Gitlab\\latineo\\latineo-api\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\common\\pipes\\validation.pipe.js:50:41)","    at transforms.reduce (E:\\projectos\\Gitlab\\latineo\\latineo-api\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\core\\pipes\\pipes-consumer.js:15:28)","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"]}}}],"data":null}
```

Comment: Hello, did you solve your problem? i'm in the exact same situation :)

Comment: no sorry, there was a guy that have it working but he was busy and i just change to rest :D. try in the discord https://discordapp.com/channels/520622812742811698/601536926268260392

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by using `graphql-upload` library. 
First i created a class for my scalar using `GraphQLUpload` from `graphql-upload`

```
import { Scalar } from '@nestjs/graphql';

import { GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload';

@Scalar('Upload')
export class Upload {
  description = 'Upload custom scalar type';

  parseValue(value) {
    return GraphQLUpload.parseValue(value);
  }

  serialize(value: any) {
    return GraphQLUpload.serialize(value);
  }

  parseLiteral(ast) {
    return GraphQLUpload.parseLiteral(ast);
  }
}
```

That i added in my Application module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
  ...
    DateScalar,
    Upload,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
     ...
      uploads: {
        maxFileSize: 10000000, // 10 MB
        maxFiles: 5,
      },
    }),
  ...
  ],
...
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

i also added Upload scalar in my graphql

```
scalar Upload
...
type Mutation {
  uploadFile(file: Upload!): String
}
```

and is worked in my resolver i had acces to the uploaded file.

```
  @Mutation()
  async uploadFile(@Args('file') file,) {
    console.log('Hello file',file)
    return "Nice !";
  }
```

(side note : I used https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client#function-createuploadlink to upload the file, in the resolver it is a Node Stream)

Comment: Lary you encounter a problem with parseLiteral expect 2 arguments ?parseLiteral(valueNode: ValueNode, variables: Maybe<{ [key: string]: any }>) {
    return GraphQLUpload.parseLiteral(valueNode, variables);
}

Comment: maybe you can help in this discord channel https://discordapp.com/channels/520622812742811698/520649487924985885

Comment: no, i used :    "apollo-server-express": "2.8.0",
    "graphql-upload": "^8.0.7"
    "@types/graphql-upload": "^8.0.0", What about you? (im already on this discord PM me if you want @Lard-man )

Comment: For those trying this now, `graphql-upload` is included in `apollo-server-express`.

Answer (score 9):

**Use** import {GraphQLUpload} from "**apollo-server-express**"
**Not** from 'graphql-upload'

```
import { Resolver, Mutation, Args } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs';

import {GraphQLUpload} from "apollo-server-express"

@Resolver('Download')
export class DownloadResolver {
    @Mutation(() => Boolean)
    async uploadFile(@Args({name: 'file', type: () => GraphQLUpload})
    {
        createReadStream,
        filename
    }): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => 
            createReadStream()
                .pipe(createWriteStream(`./uploads/${filename}`))
                .on('finish', () => resolve(true))
                .on('error', () => reject(false))
        );
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't find GraphQLUpload with apollo-server-fastify, do you know if this can work with Fastify ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Apollo Server 3 has removed "GraphQLUpload" in favor of enabling users to provide their own mechanisms for these features.

Answer (score 1):

## The correct answer for all versions of Apollo Server (fully compatible with Node 14)

1. Disable Apollo Server's built-in upload handling (for apollo 3+ not needed) and add the graphqlUploadExpress middleware to your application.

```js
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from "graphql-upload"
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from "@nestjs/common"

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      uploads: false, // disable built-in upload handling (for apollo 3+ not needed)
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(graphqlUploadExpress()).forRoutes("graphql")
  }
}
```

2. Remove the `GraphQLUpload` import from `apollo-server-core` and import from `graphql-upload` instead

```
// import { GraphQLUpload } from "apollo-server-core" <-- remove this
import { FileUpload, GraphQLUpload } from "graphql-upload"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that This old version is not fully compatible with Node 14.

> Note: Apollo Server's built-in file upload mechanism is not fully supported in Node 14 and later, and it will be removed in Apollo Server 3. For details, [see below](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads/#uploads-in-node-14-and-later).